# Targeting iOS version, and which features will be available

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios5, ios6

I am learning iOS development. And I had couple of questions, hope people don't mind
answering them here.

I was reading a chapter about ARC in a book. It seems nice. I've heard it is for iOS 5. Now, my question is, if I want my app to be available for iOS4 - does it mean I can't use ARC? (that would be a shame).

Also, I am not sure yet, for which version of iOS I should target my app. How is this reflected on my code? For example, I suppose if I target iOS5 I can't use features of iOS6 right? But if I target iOS6, then my app won't run on iOS4?
Any tips in this direction appreciated.

Comment: Why are you targeting iOS 4?

Comment: @David: Hi David, I am not, I just asked in case

Comment: If you haven't seen the pie chart on this page, you are going through unnecessary trouble for 1% of the users https://developer.apple.com/devcenter/ios/checklist/

Comment: @David: Thanks, that is really interesting link. Judging from that it seems one should just use iOS6 as a target

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I agree with David's comment and you should concentrate on iOS 6, but for information and future you would construct your app using a combination of [weak linking](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/ipad/#documentation/MacOSX/Conceptual/BPFrameworks/Concepts/WeakLinking.html) and [`respondsToSelector:`](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/ipad/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Protocols/NSObject_Protocol/Reference/NSObject.html#//apple_ref/occ/intfm/NSObject/respondsToSelector%3a) so that your app can use features of newer versions of iOS but still be compatible with older versions.

Comment: Wain, as I mentioned I just started yet. I am reading this book: http://www.bignerdranch.com/book/ios_programming_the_big_nerd_ranch_guide_rd_edition_. I will look into the keywords you mentioned a bit afterwards, right? (when I am more familiar with iOS programming).

Answer (score 0):

NO Arc can be only for iOS 5 or later but if you want your older code to be ARC enabled then you can Refactor->convert to ARC for that file. Also if you want your code to be Arc disabled then for each file you can write down "-fno-objc-arc" in build settings.

Ya new features wont be compatible for your older versions. So make sure you should be very specific for your requirements. The requirements of your App will make you conclude which iOS version you should target.

Hope this helps :)

Answer (score 0):

```
You can make individual file non-arc as per your requirement in Project.


It is very simple way to make individual file non-arc.

    Follow below steps :

    Disable ARC on individual file:

    Select desired files at Target/Build Phases/Compile Sources in Xcode

    Select .m file which you want make it NON-ARC
    PRESS ENTER
    Type **-fno-objc-arc**
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use ARC in ios 5 and above but not in IOS4.

If you targeting your app to IOS 5 then you will be able to use ARC as well. If u target it to iOS 5 then it will work on IOS 6 as well (only the deprecated features wont work on iOS 6).